# Using regex in java to get a word from a string

Tags: java, regex

I need to find the word "best" in a string using regex but it's throwing a "no match found" error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(best)");
String theString = "the best of";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theString);
matcher.matches();
String whatYouNeed = matcher.group(1);
Log.d(String.valueOf(LOG), whatYouNeed);
```

Comment: @VictorS isn't the string "the best of"?

Comment: Thanks I added a answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you have to find the string "best" in "the best of", so **find()** method suits your requirement instead of **matches()**. Please find the sample code snippet below:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("best");
    String theString = "the best of";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theString);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("found");
    }else {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, no, I need to store the pattern that I found in a variable. That's why I need matches.

Comment: `find` will do the same as `matches` it just looks for a partial match instead of having to match the whole string. You still have access to groups after find. The major difference is you can call find multiple times to find each instance that matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use **find()** not matches!

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(best)");
    String theString = "the best of";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theString);
    if(matcher.find())
        System.out.println("Hi!");
}
```

Comment: Well, no, I need to store the pattern that I found in a variable. That's why I need matches.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is this.

```
String theString = "the best of";

String regex = "(best)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);

while (m.find()) {
    String result = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("found: " + result);
}
```

outputs:

```
found: best
```